# Theming certain system block like user cancellation

Tags: 7, users

I have difficulties in theming user cancellation form (user/%/cancel).

Basically I'm trying to achieve:

1. add h1 tag
2. wrap form in a div
3. add text between the buttons

[image: Cancel account]

Although this form has the ID = user-cancel-confirm-form, I can't theme it the same way like User profile page (user/%/edit).

This is what printing $var['block'] at preprocess_block tells me:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [bid] => 120
    [module] => system
    [delta] => main
    [theme] => mytheme
    [status] => 1
    [weight] => -24
    [region] => content
    [custom] => 0
    [visibility] => 0
    [pages] => 
    [title] => 
    [cache] => -1
    [subject] => 
    [last_in_region] => 1
)
```

I tried:

**mytheme_theme()** : nothing happens

```
'user_cancel_confirm_form' => array(
            'render element'    => 'form',
            'template'          => 'edit-acct-cancellation',
            'path'              => $path . '/templates/edit',
            //'variables' => array('form' => NULL,'form_title' => 'Cancel Account'),
        ),
```

**mytheme_preprocess_block()** : affects all block-system-main

```
if($vars['block']->bid == 120){
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__user__cancel';
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

As to date, solution that works is to override the whole page with page--user--cancel.tpl.php But seriously, there must be a better solution (/proper) out there.

Any advise is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem is - you kinda mixed couple problems. First is really theming, like form theming to add a div, and maybe block theming to wrap it's title in H1. Other is to modify form to add texts between fields, something to be done with form alter. So your question happens to be more like "provide me with solution" than "I have this precise, well defined, narrow problem" situation.

Comment: I have no idea that such a simple goal requires so many processes. So there's no way to solve it in one go like using form alter only? But thanks for helping me to see my problems better. :) afterall, im a newbie.

Comment: Well, you basically want to change everything about a block. It would be simpler to implement it from scratch. It's easy to alter each single one aspect of provided forms and blocks, but if you want to alter everything, why bother with altering at all?

Comment: I guess coz this particular block is a system block, or part of the core, since it is not enlisted in the Block lists...
I have no choice but to alter.